# Update, insert and delete from an XML into MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, phpmyadmin, crud

Im working on a web that imports data from a XML archive to a database in MySQL and then that data is showed in the front end of the website.
I've been watching articles to do it, and i make the insert correctly, but i cant delete or update.
I will show my data and try to explain the best as i can.
I've got an `php` named `importacion.php` and it has the following code:

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <h2 align="center">Importación inmuebles</h2>
        <br />
        <div class="col-md-9" style="margin:0 auto; float:none;">
         <span id="message"></span>

         <form method="post" id="import_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group">
           <label>Selecciona un archivo XML porfavor</label><br/>
           <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
          </div>
          <br />
          <div class="form-group">
           <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Importar"/>
          </div>
         </form>

        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#import_form').on('submit', function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
           url:"_import.php",
           method:"POST",
           data: new FormData(this),
           contentType:false,
           cache:false,
           processData:false,
           beforeSend:function(){
            $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled'),
            $('#submit').val('Importing...');
           },
           success:function(data)
           {
            $('#message').html(data);
            $('#import_form')[0].reset();
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#submit').val('Importar');
           }
          })

          setInterval(function(){
           $('#message').html('');
          }, 5000);

         });
        });
        </script>
```

When i upload the XML and click on the button, we follow to _import.php, that have the following code:

```
 <?php 
        sleep(3);
        $output = '';

        if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']) &&  $_FILES['file']['name'] != '')
        {
           $valid_extension = array('xml');
           $file_data = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);
           $file_extension = end($file_data);
           if(in_array($file_extension, $valid_extension))
         {
            $data = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
           $connect = new PDO('mysql:host="localhost";dbname="dbname"','username', 'password');
                  $query = "
                    INSERT INTO Inmuebles 
                     (idInmueble, fechaInmueble, refInmueble, grupoInmueble) 
                     VALUES(:idInmueble, :fechaInmueble, :refInmueble, :grupoInmueble);
                    ";          

            $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
            for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
            {
             $statement->execute(
              array(
               ':idInmueble'  => $data->Inmueble[$i]->Id,
               ':fechaInmueble'  => $data->Inmueble[$i]->Fecha,
               ':refInmueble' => $data->Inmueble[$i]->Referencia,
               ':grupoInmueble'   => $data->Inmueble[$i]->GrupoInmueble
              )
             );

            }
            $result = $statement->fetchAll();
            if(isset($result))
            {
             $output = '<div class="alert alert-success">Importación realizada correctamente</div>';
            }
           }
           else
           {
            $output = '<div class="alert alert-warning">Archivo no aceptado</div>';
           }
        } else {
         $output = '<div class="alert alert-warning">Por favor selecciona un archivo XML</div>';
        }

        echo $output;
```

This code works perfectly, but i cant update or delete when the data of the xml is updated.

Now I've tried to update the query to this, but it doesn't work:

```
<?php 
        sleep(3);
        $output = '';

        if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']) &&  $_FILES['file']['name'] != '')
        {
           $valid_extension = array('xml');
           $file_data = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);
           $file_extension = end($file_data);
           if(in_array($file_extension, $valid_extension))
         {
            $data = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename','user', 'password');

             if ('idInmueble' === true) {
               //Update
               $query = "
             UPDATE Inmuebles SET 
               idInmueble = :idInmueble,
               fechaInmueble = :fechaInmueble,
               refInmueble = :refInmueble,
               grupoInmueble = :grupoInmueble
             WHERE idInmueble = :idInmueble;
             ";
             }else {
                 if ('idInmueble' === false) {
                  //insert
                  $query = "
                    INSERT INTO Inmuebles 
                     (idInmueble, fechaInmueble, refInmueble, grupoInmueble) 
                     VALUES(:idInmueble, :fechaInmueble, :refInmueble, :grupoInmueble);
                    ";
                 }else {
                   //delete
                   $query = "
                     DELETE FROM Inmuebles 
                     WHERE idInmueble = :idInmueble;
                     ";
                }
            } 


            $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
            for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
            {
             $statement->execute(
              array(
               ':idInmueble'  => $data->Inmueble[$i]->Id,
               ':fechaInmueble'  => $data->Inmueble[$i]->Fecha,
               ':refInmueble' => $data->Inmueble[$i]->Referencia,
               ':grupoInmueble'   => $data->Inmueble[$i]->GrupoInmueble
              )
             );

            }
            $result = $statement->fetchAll();
            if(isset($result))
            {
             $output = '<div class="alert alert-success">Importación realizada correctamente</div>';
            }
           }
           else
           {
            $output = '<div class="alert alert-warning">Archivo no aceptado</div>';
           }
        } else {
         $output = '<div class="alert alert-warning">Por favor selecciona un archivo XML</div>';
        }

        echo $output;
```

And the XML file is the following one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Inmuebles>
    <Inmueble>
        <Id>393926</Id>
        <Fecha>20-11-2019 18:31:18</Fecha>
        <Referencia>2119</Referencia>
        <GrupoInmueble>Chalets Update</GrupoInmueble>
    </Inmueble>
    <Inmueble>
        <Id>39392de6</Id>
        <Fecha>20-12-2019 18:31:18</Fecha>
        <Referencia>aass</Referencia>
        <GrupoInmueble>Prueba</GrupoInmueble>
    </Inmueble>
</Inmuebles>
```

**NEW EDIT**
I've been trying some new code on importacion.php and it seem like this:

```
<?php 
        sleep(3);
        $output = '';

        if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']) &&  $_FILES['file']['name'] != '')
        {
           $valid_extension = array('xml');
           $file_data = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);
           $file_extension = end($file_data);
           if(in_array($file_extension, $valid_extension))
         {
            $data = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname','user', 'password');

            //-----------------------------------query de insercion
           $check_query = "SELECT idInmueble FROM Inmuebles";

          $resultados = mysqli_query($db, $check_query);
          while($mob = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados));

           if(empty($mob)) {
            $query = "
                    INSERT INTO Inmuebles
                     (idInmueble, fechaInmueble, refInmueble, grupoInmueble) 
                     VALUES(:idInmueble, :fechaInmueble, :refInmueble, :grupoInmueble);
                    "; 
           }else {
              $query = "
                  UPDATE Inmuebles SET 
                     fechaInmueble = :fechaInmueble,
                     refInmueble = :refInmueble,
                     grupoInmueble = :grupoInmueble
                  WHERE idInmueble = '". $mob ."';
              ";
           }

            //---------------------------------------fin query insercion

            $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
            for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
            {
             $statement->execute(
              array(
               ':idmobiliaInmueble'  => $data->Inmueble[$i]->Id,
               ':fechaInmueble'  => $data->Inmueble[$i]->Fecha,
               ':refInmueble' => $data->Inmueble[$i]->Referencia,
               ':grupoInmueble'   => $data->Inmueble[$i]->GrupoInmueble
              )
             );

            }
            $result = $statement->fetchAll();
            if(isset($result))
            {
             $output = '<div class="alert alert-success">Importación realizada correctamente</div>';
            }
           }
           else
           {
            $output = '<div class="alert alert-warning">Archivo no aceptado</div>';
           }
        } else {
         $output = '<div class="alert alert-warning">Por favor selecciona un archivo XML</div>';
        }

        echo $output;
```

The insert works correctly, but the update dont, it works without the while sentence, so i dont know whats going on, aprreciated the help, thank you in advice!

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting `if ('idInmueble' === true)` to do?

Comment: It means that, if there is a idInmueble that alredy exists, it will be updated if the xml contains new data  of that 'idInmueble' or deleted if the xml has no longer the 'idInmueble'

Comment: But a string will never be identical to `true` because it is not a boolean. So this comparison will always evaluate to false (see here https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#type.comparisons-strict)

Comment: @digijay Mmm i see, gonna try to get the value of the xml array into a variable and switch the ```true```to that variable, thanks for the comment!

Comment: You're also not changing your parameters to match the placeholders in your statements. Have you read how prepared statements work in PDO?